# Show navbar on mousover

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

I'm working on a website and I thought it would be cool to have the navbar only show when you move your mouse to the top of the screen. Is that even possible? because I cant find any tutorials on it. Anyway, is there also a way for it to not just appear, but more slide down from the top? Kind of like the windows taskbar does only upside down. Thanks!

This is the site if anyone wants to see the navbar right now: https://www.oakparknerds.tk/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few approaches that could be taken to achieve this. The easiest is to just use CSS to animate the margin-top of the nav bar when hovered. You can set the nav bar to have no background color, then on hover change the color to make it appear.

Example with nav bar ID of #slidingBox:

```
#slidingBox {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: none;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#slidingBox:hover {
  margin-top: 0px;
  background-color: #d9dada;
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/smulvihill/9yv0pc6u/10/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do this with jquery and css. I changed the background color to orange so you can see it in action.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="nav_container" style="border:1px solid black;width:100%;height:300px;">
  <nav id="my_nav" style="display:none;width:100%; height:200px;background-color:orange;">

    <a href="#">Links</a>

</nav>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#nav_container").mouseover(function(){
        $("#my_nav").slideDown(3000);
    });
    $("#nav_container").mouseout(function(){
        $("#my_nav").fadeOut();
    });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```